# Node.js para reencaminhamento de informações de uma API de terceiros

Tags: node.js, api

O que eu quero fazer com o Node.js é basicamente OUVIR uma API (jSON) e processar os resultados para enviar para vários clientes.

Exemplo:

[image: esquema da execução]

O que eu quero saber é:
Esse Meu computador VPS tem que existir mesmo e ficar executando a aplicação do servidor durante 24 horas?

Eu pensei em algo como um Crontab para substituir o VPS, mas acho que estou equivocado quanto a isso, porque o Node.js deve ficar "OUVINDO" a API e não acessando a mesma através de várias requisições em um determinado intervalo de tempo.

Será que eu poderia deixar o script rodando no próprio servidor de forma eterna?

Eu vejo vários apps de notificações que recolhem dados de terceiros e fico imaginando se é assim que eles funcionam.

Answer (score 0):

Pesquisa sobre [socket.io](https://socket.io/), ele mantém uma conexão bidirecional(**websocket**) com qualquer cliente que se conectar, logo, você pode criar salas privadas, mecanismos de login, etc.

Pode emitir mensagens do cliente para o servidor e vice-versa.